# JSON Structure to insert a null value for a property into Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

What JSON Structure is used to insert a null value for a property into Google Cloud Datastore using the REST API?

Usually you define a property name, valuetype, and value, like so:

```
var property = {
  propertyname: { integerValue: 4 }
};
```

With integerValue denoting the valuetype. All the valuetypes can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Properties_and_value_types) but I can not work out the structure for null.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the JSON API.

I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/41 to track it.

In the proto API, you would do this:

```
Property property = Property.newBuilder()
    .setName("propertyName")
    .setValue(Value.getDefaultInstance())
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Ed, but I get { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
       message: 'Property "propertyName" has no value.' } ],
  code: 400,
  message: 'Property "propertyName" has no value.' } error with that structure

Comment: You're absolutely right -- updated my answer to indicate that it is a bug.